# Send email in Java puts '>' character in front of the word "From"

Tags: java, email, text

When i send email messages in Java, if the word "From" is the first word of any line, a '>' character gets appended the beginning of the word, how do I stop this?

This is my Text:

```
The following transaction has been posted:

From Scholarship Name - $scholName
To Department - $deptName
```

This is what gets sent out

```
The following transaction has been posted:

>From Scholarship Name - $scholName
To Department - $deptName
```

I can put "From" as the first word of any line and I get this.  If i put "From" anywhere else then it works fine.

My Code:

```
private String sendMsg(String subject, String msgString, String[] toMail, List<String> ccMailList) throws C3Exception {
    String returnMsg = null;


        MimeMessage msg = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);

        helper.setTo(toMail);

        if (ccMailList != null && !ccMailList.isEmpty()) {
            String[] ccMail = new String[ccMailList.size()];
            for(int x = 0; x < ccMailList.size(); x++) {
                ccMail[x] = ccMailList.get(x);
            }

            helper.setCc(ccMail);
        }

        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setFrom("noreply@email.com");
        helper.setSentDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        helper.setText(new String(msgString));
        mailSender.send(msg);

    return returnMsg;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you inspecting the output? Lines beginning with "From" are message separators in unix mailboxes, and are escaped by prepending a ">". Actual mailreaders should display everything properly.

Comment: I'm reading the email in my email client, Thunderbird.  BUT, since you mentioned that I checked in a different email client and its not there.  so it must be something specific to Thunderbird that causing this.